# How to order sms by date sent

Tags: php, laravel, twilio, laravel-blade

I'm using twilio to send and recieve messages between users on my website. I can successfully display both inbound, and outgoing sms messages.

I retrieve my message like so.

```
$receivedMessages = $twilio->messages
                         ->read(array(
                                 "from" => $user->phone,
                                 "to" => $siteNumber,
                             )
                         );

     $sentMessages = $twilio->messages
                         ->read(array(
                                 "from" => $siteNumber,
                                 "to" => $user->phone,
                             )
                         );

     $combinedMessages = array_merge($receivedMessages, $sentMessages);
```

I pass the combniedmessage variable to my view, then loop through them and apply a different style to the inbound and outgoing messages.

```
 <ul class="text-container incoming-container">
           @foreach($combinedMessages as $message)
             <li class="text-message
              @if($message->direction == 'inbound')
                incoming-text
              @elseif($message->direction == 'outbound-api')
                outgoing-text
              @endif">
              <span>
                {{$message->body }}
              </span></br>
              <small>
                {{ (string)$message->dateCreated->format('d-m-Y H:i:s')}}
              </small>
             </li>
          @endforeach
         </ul>
```

The inbound are displayed first, and the outbound are displayed second. How can I show them in order of when they were sent, regardless of the direction.

Comment: Your arrays only have "to" and "from" keys. How are we supposed to know the date and time?

Answer (score 1):

What you need to so is sort your `$combinedMessages` array using a custom sort function that will sort by the message date of the object.

Check out uasort() command here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php

```
<?php
// Sample Comparison function
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ( $a->message_timestamp == $b->message_timestamp ) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ( $a->message_timestamp < $b->message_timestamp ) ? -1 : 1;
}

uasort( $combinedMessages, 'cmp' );
?>
```